# Switch off power when 0v is sensed / Short to ground

Tags: detector

I have already posted this question but I made a mess of the diagram so deleted it and am posting again, apologies to anyone to answered the original question.

I'm fairly new to electronics and am stuck at how to get a circuit working. I have 2 peripherals connected in the circuit, a smoke detector and a relay, both operates at 12v DC and are continuously energized (ie always powered on). When the smoke detector is triggered an internal switch is operated and the detectors output shorts to ground.

What I would like to do is when the smoke detector is triggered, use the output of the detector (which is a short a to ground) to turn the relay off (ie no current is flowing through the relay) and when the detector returns to normal operation (its internal switch is off and there is no short to ground from the output) the relay returns back to normal and be energized.

I have looked at NPN transistors but they need a positive supply to operate the transistor and my detector outputs a ground. I have also looked at PNP transistors however they operate the transistor with a ground signal. I am wanting the opposite effect, ie to switch off when a short to ground signal is output from the detector. I’ve included a diagram which should hopefully explain the circuit a bit better.

Thanks in advance for any help.

NOTE:

The detector also has a +12v output as a fail safe, if the detector is working properly it outputs +12v which is used to power the relay, and hence you know there isn't a fault with the detector as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An output that shorts to ground when active is commonly called an NPN output (like the transistor).

It will be easiest to configure this so that the relay is *energized* when when the output is active. Simple connect the other side of the relay to 12v. That's the opposite of what you're asking for, but if you rewire the relay so that it's normally closed you will get a similar effect.

If you don't want to do that, because of power draw, or some failsafe issue, you will need another component or 2. Configure a mosfet with a pullup so that it is energizing the relay by default, then use the pull down to turn the mosfet *off* when the smoke detector output goes low.

Whatever you do, it's a good idea to add a flyback diode across the relay.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that won't work, I simplified the circuit, but the detector also has a +12v output as a fail safe, if the detector is working properly it outputs +12v which is used to power the relay, and hence you know there isn't a fault with the detector. I've added a new diagram to the original post which shows this.

Comment: But I think the mosfet will work, can you tell me what mosfet to use? eg will a 2N7000 be OK? Also, if I use a solid state relay, will I still need the flyback diode? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you should add a flyback no matter what. That mosfet should work as long as the relay uses less than 200ma.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I checked the realy and it draws 15ma so all good there, for the flyback diode will a sr106t be OK?

Comment: Yeah that should work

Comment: Thanks Drew, i've got the mosfet on order and when it arrives I'll give it a go ...

Comment: I have a similar problem which I think you might be able to help me with Drew, I've posted it here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506577/reverse-nc-output-to-no-for-a-card-reader/

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly you don't need anything except a different relay.

You are currently using a relay with Normally Open (N.O.) contacts. When power is applied to the coil the contacts are closed. It is perfectly possible to buy relays with Normally Closed (N.C.) contacts. These will have contacts which are closed with no current in the coil, and open when the relay is energized. And, for that matter, a Single Pole, Double Throw (SPDT) relay will have a common lead, a N.O. lead, and an N.C. lead, with the last two contacts connecting to the common when appropriate.

The only question is, is your smoke detector output capable of handling the relay coil current? If so, you simply wire it as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZotlf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the smoke detector is not triggered, the relay coil is not fully connected, so the output will be at the resting state, with the COM and N.C. contacts closed. When the detector activates, the relay coil will draw current and the N.C. contact will open.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that won't work, I simplified the circuit, but the detector also has a +12v output as a fail safe, if the detector is working properly it outputs +12v which is used to power the relay, and hence you know there isn't a fault with the relay. I've added a new diagram to the original post which shows this.